# How to read 'hms' time format beyond 24-hours?

Tags: r, datetime, formatting, time-series

I am doing a time series where activity measurements were taken in 1-minute intervals over 48 hours. I am using the variable "Time Elapsed" as my x-value. In Excel I had it formatted as time up to the 48 hours, but when importing it into R anything over 24 hours was registered as `N/A` As a result, my graphs stop at 24 hours.

Entering `str(data)` has given me this:

```
$ TimeElapsed: 'hms' num  00:01:30 00:02:30 00:03:30 00:04:30 ...
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"`
```

The formatting is correct < 24 hours, and then after that becomes `NA`.

On someone's advice, I tried linking it to the RunDate:

```
z1 <- format(data$RunDate,"%Y-%m-%d")
z2 <- format(data$TimeElapsed, "%H:%M:%S")
## RunDate and TimeElapsed combined:
z3 <- as.POSIXct(paste(z1,z2,sep = " "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
start_date <- "2019-06-11"
start_time <- "14:00:00"
start_dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(start_date,start_time,sep = " "), 
                       format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

But only got this error message:

> Error in format.default(data$RunDate, "%Y-%m-%d"): invalid 'trim' argument

Some example data of mine would be:

```
ID       TimeElapsed   RunDate       Activity
Zx8      47:52:30      15-Jun-19      30
Zx8      47:53:30      15-Jun-19      0  
Zx8      47:54:30      15-Jun-19      6
Zx12     47:55:30      15-Jun-19      23
Zx12     47:56:30      15-Jun-19      14
Zx12     47:57:30      15-Jun-19      0
```

How do I get R to read the time format beyond 24-hours?

Comment: Without the excel file its hard to tell. However, you can determine how to read in values, e.g. via `readxl::read_excel(col_types=)`. I suggest to read in the specific column as character and proceed in R

Comment: I think one assumption of all of those time-related functions is that it is time*-of-day*, which is not what you want it to me. If this is about *calculations*, then perhaps just using raw seconds (up to 172800) could suffice. If this is about presentation, then I suspect you'll have to have your own function for printing seconds as `h:mm:ss` over more than 24 hours, it's rather direct calculation. This doesn't fix your importing from Excel, in which case you'll need to do something like @BenBolker's answer of manually parsing the `character` (not `POSIXt`) column.

Comment: Yep, hms is the wrong class for what you're trying to do. There are alternatives: seconds, difftime, or `lubridate::period`.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need a correct number (i.e. you're not trying to do fancy downstream processing/plotting with a H:M:S format), you can use a simple recipe based on `strsplit()` to convert the H:M:S format to hours:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
ID       TimeElapsed   RunDate       Activity
Zx8      47:52:30      15-Jun-19      30
Zx8      47:53:30      15-Jun-19      0  
Zx8      47:54:30      15-Jun-19      6
Zx12     47:55:30      15-Jun-19      23
Zx12     47:56:30      15-Jun-19      14
Zx12     47:57:30      15-Jun-19      0
")

dd$NumTime <- sapply(strsplit(dd$TimeElapsed,":"),
        function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)*c(1,1/60,1/3600)))
```

(Converting to seconds instead of hours should be straightforward if you prefer that.)

When plotting, the simplest thing would be to specify tick labels manually (e.g. ticklabels "0:00", "24:00", "48:00"). If using `ggplot2` you could manually define your own transformed axis (with `?scales::trans_new`, using an identity transformation/inverse transformation and specifying an appropriate function for `format`).